# installing libudev header file mac

Tags: c++, macos

Beginner coder here, working in cpp - I am trying to install header file for libudev but have not been able to do so. Does anyone have experience and/or advice on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Installing the header by itself, without the library, would be a pointless exercise.  Install the library and its associated development components, which should include the header.  Whether you can actually do that is unclear to me -- I see some hints that indeed you can, but I've yet to turn up any details.  Udev is not a native Mac thing.

Comment: Thanks, John! It seems like I can't get Udev on a mac. However, I am hoping to make use of the 'diskutil activity' command, hopefully that helps someone else in the future!

Comment: `diskutil activity` seems to have been part of OS X since Lion.  What do you need libudev for?

Comment: Hey, sorry I was inactive for a bit. I was able to install libudev. I'm exploring both options to alert me to when a hard drive has been introduced to the computer. Let me know if you have any new thoughts and thanks for helping out, guys!